# Distributed scraping to meet terms of access

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a relatively large number (approximately 10,000) of papers from PubMed. The terms of access state:

`Do not make concurrent requests, even at off-peak times.`

Does this rule out using a distributed method?

Comment: Yes. Well, if they can detect it...

Comment: You are violating their terms of access.  You might get away with it for awhile, but consider the long-term consequences when you are caught.

Comment: I'm not doing it...